# How do I determine whether an Excel worksheet contains no values using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm coding a Python 3.7.2 script to check for unused worksheets in an Excel file, and I need a way to determine if the current worksheet contains no values. Previously when I coded in VBA, I would find the last-used-row and last-used-column to check if the sheet was 'empty', but the max_column and max_row functions in openpyxl take into account non-value data like formatting which I want to ignore. Is there any way to check if none of the cells of a given worksheet contain any values?

Previously when I coded in VBA, I would find the last-used-row and last-used-column to check if the sheet was 'empty', but the max_column and max_row functions in openpyxl take into account non-value data like formatting which I want to ignore.

Ideally I'd be able to find a way to get the last_used_column and last_used_row like I used to in VBA, but I'd appreciate it if anyone could tell me of any tools I could use to build a simple function where you pass it a worksheet and it spits out True or False depending on whether it has no values or not.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667315/determine-if-worksheet-is-empty-in-openpyxl

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately it looks like the API has changed in the past two years and ReadOnlyWorksheet has no attribute '_cells'. If there's any way I can get the used cells in a sheet that would be great!

Comment: a one-line to get a list of all names of empty sheets: `[name for name in wb.get_sheet_names() if not (wb.get_sheet_by_name(name).get_cell_collection())]`, with `wb = load_workbook('workbook.xlsx')`

Comment: No, there are no shortcuts for this: you have to check the cells yourself and you should have mentioned that you're working in read-only mode.

Comment: Added answer in a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71326862/9176744

Comment: Added answer here to a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71326862/9176744

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to my suggestion in a comment, `ws.get_cell_collection()` is deprecated, but you could iterate over the `openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet` module's
 [values](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.values) property, since (from the docs):

> **values**
>   Produces all cell values in the worksheet, by row
>
> Type: generator

With a workbook `workbook.xlsx` containing two worksheets, `Sheet1` does contain some cell with values, but `Sheet2` is visibly empty with all empty cells:

```
wb = load_workbook('workbook.xlsx')

for name in wb.get_sheet_names():
    isempty = False
    for row in wb.get_sheet_by_name(name).values:
        if all(value == None for value in row):
            isempty = True
        else:
            isempty = False
    if isempty:
        print(name)
```

outputs the empty sheet(s):

```
Sheet2
```

Although this works it is a bit more complicated than using only:

```
empty_sheets = [name for name in wb.get_sheet_names() if not (wb.get_sheet_by_name(name).get_cell_collection())]
```

which still works albeit deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a persistent, vexing problem with Python3 and OpenPyXL; hopefully the dev teams will address this more elegantly in future releases.  In the mean time, my **inelegant** solution relies on the max_column max_row tests described by previous posters:

```
for sheet in workBook.worksheets:
    if (sheet.max_column == 1) and (sheet.max_row == 1):
    # see if cell is empty
        if sheet.cell(row=1,column=1).value == None:
            print('Sheet ' + sheet.title + ' is empty.  Ignoring ... ')
            continue

    do other stuff
```

I inserted this *if* test in a script that converted any *.xlsx? files in a source directory to CSV files to get the processing past a "TypeError: 'tuple'" error.  The script would work fine until it encountered any empty sheet in a workbook; then it would fail.  Those simple few lines solved the issue.