# Undestanding how the append method of Worksheet from openpyxl module works

Tags: python, openpyxl

Here is some code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('myfile.xlsx')
ws = wb.active 
# data for filling Excel table
rows = (
   (88, 46, 57),
   (89, 38, 12),
   (23, 59, 78),
   (56, 21, 98),
   (24, 18, 43),
   (34, 15, 67)
)
for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)
wb.save('my_changed_file.xlsx')
```

After executing the code above, I expected to see the Excel table filled in from the first row, but the table was filled in from the second row.

Why does the `append` method work so?

Comment: What does the title have anything to do with the question?

Comment: Where do you see an active attribute on worksheet for that matter?

Comment: I am sorry. TItle was corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really `append`'s fault. Every workbook has at least one row and column when it starts. I had a similar issue some time back: [Determine if worksheet is empty in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37667315/2988730). According to the author (Charlie Clark), the internal counters `max_row` and `max_column` must always be strictly positive, so `append` will always write to the second row.

You can always set the cells in a loop where you control the indices, which is very similar to what `append` does as a convenience anyway:

```
for r, row in enumerate(data, start=1):
    for c, value in enumerate(row, start=1):
        worksheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value = value
```

Once A1 is filled, `append` will work exactly as you expect.

Comment: There is a case, however, when `append` does write to the first row, not the second.
It's when instead of opening an existing workbook with `load_workbook` we use a new one created by `openpyxl` like this: `wb = Workbook()`

Comment: `load_workbook()` will depend on what the previous application did. If in doubt delete the worksheet and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - empty row came automatically and had no idea why until this thread.

Will share my final solution:

```
"""Goal: adding new rows to a worksheet without empty row"""

"""python imports"""
import openpyxl
import pandas

"""Load input workbook"""
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='file.xlsx')

"""Activate worksheet named 'data'."""
ws = wb['data']

"""Read in new data from data1.csv to pandas.dataframe"""
new_dataframe = pandas.read_csv("data1.csv")

"""Iterate over dataframe rows and write values to worksheet"""
for i, row in new_dataframe.iterrows():
    # ws.append leaves first line empty
    # to get data written from first row,  need to use writing to cell
    if i == 0:
        for c, value in enumerate(row, start=1):
            ws.cell(row=2, column=c).value = value
    else:
        current_row = [row.col1, row.col2, row.col3]
        ws.append(current_row)

"""Change table range"""
ws.tables['MyTable'].ref = "A1:E5"

"""Save workbook"""
wb.save(filename='file.xlsx')
```